# how does amazon SQS handle identical messages?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

if you send a message to an specific Amazon SQS queue, and keep sending the same message to the same queue many times, ... does amazon sqs handles them as separate messages ?? or does it detect it's the same messages and only stores one message in the queue ??

Thanks

Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will create the same message over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer from Sep 21 '11 is incorrect, at least when FIFO queues are used.  (Fifo queues were not available in 2011.)

Fifo queues support both content-based deduplication, and sender-managed deduplication.  In either case, when a duplicate message is sent, the send is accepted, but no new message is created on the queue.  This applies to duplicates within the 5-minute deduplication window.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/using-messagededuplicationid-property.html